# make `previous-buffer` and `next-buffer` to ignore some buffers

Tags: buffers

in Helm I ignore some buffers from showing when using `C-x b`, I'm looking for a way to make the commands `previous-buffer` and `next-buffer` behave the same ignoring some buffers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can as of 2022 (since Emacs 27.1?) achieve the same result as in the accepted answer with Emacs' built-in functionality, using `switch-to-prev-buffer-skip`. For example, here is my current config (inspired by @phils' answer):

```el
(defcustom aj8/buffer-skip-regexp
  (rx bos (or (or "*Backtrace*" "*Compile-Log*" "*Completions*"
                  "*Messages*" "*package*" "*Warnings*"
                  "*Async-native-compile-log*")
              (seq "magit-diff" (zero-or-more anything))
              (seq "magit-process" (zero-or-more anything))
              (seq "magit-revision" (zero-or-more anything))
              (seq "magit-stash" (zero-or-more anything)))
              eos)
  "Regular expression matching buffers ignored by `next-buffer' and
`previous-buffer'."
  :type 'regexp)

(defun aj8/buffer-skip-p (window buffer bury-or-kill)
  "Return t if BUFFER name matches `aj8/buffer-skip-regexp'."
  (string-match-p aj8/buffer-skip-regexp (buffer-name buffer)))

(setq switch-to-prev-buffer-skip 'aj8/buffer-skip-p)
```

Answer (score 13):

```el
(defcustom my-skippable-buffers '("*Messages*" "*scratch*" "*Help*")
  "Buffer names ignored by `my-next-buffer' and `my-previous-buffer'."
  :type '(repeat string))

(defun my-change-buffer (change-buffer)
  "Call CHANGE-BUFFER until current buffer is not in `my-skippable-buffers'."
  (let ((initial (current-buffer)))
    (funcall change-buffer)
    (let ((first-change (current-buffer)))
      (catch 'loop
        (while (member (buffer-name) my-skippable-buffers)
          (funcall change-buffer)
          (when (eq (current-buffer) first-change)
            (switch-to-buffer initial)
            (throw 'loop t)))))))

(defun my-next-buffer ()
  "Variant of `next-buffer' that skips `my-skippable-buffers'."
  (interactive)
  (my-change-buffer 'next-buffer))

(defun my-previous-buffer ()
  "Variant of `previous-buffer' that skips `my-skippable-buffers'."
  (interactive)
  (my-change-buffer 'previous-buffer))

(global-set-key [remap next-buffer] 'my-next-buffer)
(global-set-key [remap previous-buffer] 'my-previous-buffer)
```

Or if you wanted to ignore buffer names matching a pattern, you could use this variant.

```el
(defcustom my-skippable-buffer-regexp
  (rx bos (or "*Messages*" "*scratch*" "*Help*") eos)
  "Matching buffer names are ignored by `my-next-buffer'
and `my-previous-buffer'."
  :type 'regexp)

(defun my-change-buffer (change-buffer)
  "Call CHANGE-BUFFER until `my-skippable-buffer-regexp' doesn't match."
  (let ((initial (current-buffer)))
    (funcall change-buffer)
    (let ((first-change (current-buffer)))
      (catch 'loop
        (while (string-match-p my-skippable-buffer-regexp (buffer-name))
          (funcall change-buffer)
          (when (eq (current-buffer) first-change)
            (switch-to-buffer initial)
            (throw 'loop t)))))))

(defun my-next-buffer ()
  "Variant of `next-buffer' that skips `my-skippable-buffer-regexp'."
  (interactive)
  (my-change-buffer 'next-buffer))

(defun my-previous-buffer ()
  "Variant of `previous-buffer' that skips `my-skippable-buffer-regexp'."
  (interactive)
  (my-change-buffer 'previous-buffer))

(global-set-key [remap next-buffer] 'my-next-buffer)
(global-set-key [remap previous-buffer] 'my-previous-buffer)
```

For the example from the comments, to tell this latter version to also skip all buffer names beginning with `helm`, we could use:

```el
(setq my-skippable-buffer-regexp
      (rx bos (or (or "*Messages*" "*scratch*" "*Help*")
                  (seq "helm" (zero-or-more anything)))
          eos))
```

Comment: What should I do to hide all `helm*` buffers as well?

Comment: yes it does! Thanks @phils

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly.  Please test.

Comment: With the current updated code it works without a problem. If I add new patterns would I just add `(seq "patter" (zero-or-more anything)` line?

Comment: You can do, but I would suggest using `(seq (or "helm" "foo" "bar") (zero-or-more anything))` to match a variety of prefixes.

Comment: Also what could we do to skip all the buffers names ending with `.txt`?

Comment: Well if `(seq "helm" (zero-or-more anything))` is "all buffer names beginning with `helm`" then what's your guess at the equivalent "all buffer names ending with `.txt`" ?

Comment: `(anything zero-or-more)`?

Comment: It will be `(seq (zero-or-more anything) ".txt")`.  The sequence of "zero-or-more of any character" followed by `.txt`.  Just like the earlier example was the sequence of `helm` followed by "zero-or-more of any character".

Comment: Thanks. Ah basically its `*.txt`. I get confused when `(zero-or-more anything)` is actually alias for `*`.

Comment: You're thinking of shell globbing syntax, rather than regexps. `(zero-or-more anything)` is `rx` syntax for the regexp `"\\(.\\|\n\\)*"`, with the trailing `*` being the zero-or-more quantifier, and the preceding part matching any character.

Comment: I.e. almost the same as the regexp `.*` except that `.` doesn't match newlines.

Comment: this one still has some problem, dunno what is root cause but in my system the next-buffer one stops after a few buffers while the prev-buffer keeps cycling through???

Answer (score 9):

Here are two ways:

1. If you take a look at the definition of function `switch-to-next-buffer` (in library `window.el`) you will see that it filters the buffers by the predicate (if any) that is the value of frame parameter `buffer-predicate`. That function is used by `next-buffer`.

   You can set that frame parameter to a predicate that filters the way you want.
2. You can simply advise function `switch-to-next-buffer` to filter the way you want. You will essentially replace its definition by almost the same definition, but filter additionally the way you want.

Similarly for `switch-to-previous-buffer`.