# How to skip some buffers when use prev-buffer/next-buffer?

Tags: buffers

windows 10, emacs 26.1

Suppose I open 10 buffers.
If I can use `prev-buffer` (`C-x left`) / `next-buffer` (`C-x right`) to go to prev/next buffers. It's very comfortable.

But I need when I do this to skip some buffers. E.g. buffers whose names start with `helm-xxx`.

Is it possible?

Comment: Sure, write a custom command taking this in account.

Comment: Skipping some buffers is a [classic](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17687/make-previous-buffer-and-next-buffer-to-ignore-some-buffers)

Answer (score 6):

You can control which buffers `next-buffer` will consider with the `buffer-predicate` frame parameter. An example which filters out all buffers that match `"helm"`:

```
(defun my-buffer-predicate (buffer)
  (if (string-match "helm" (buffer-name buffer))
      nil
    t))
(set-frame-parameter nil 'buffer-predicate 'my-buffer-predicate)
```